# JDO with Java EE 6 (CDI and JTA?)

Tags: java-ee-6, jdo, cdi, jta

I apologize if this is an obvious question, but I'm going through the Java EE 6 tutorial while reading a couple books and it's getting hard to correlate all of the information.

I'm doing a little comparison between JDO and JPA. I understand that with JPA and an application server, I can quite easily say something like:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  // methods that use the JPA entity manager...
}
```

Then, within my own methods, I can use `em` to get at a JPA EntityManager. Whatever methods I write will (by default) automatically create or join up with an existing transaction.

I'd like to have this much fun with JDO. I suspect the right answer is to use CDI. I'm not sure what that would look like though, perhaps this?

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

  @Resource
  private PersistenceManager em;

  // methods that use the JDO persistence manager...
}
```

But this guesswork leaves me with more questions than answers.

1. How do I tell Glassfish or whatever my Java EE 6 application server turns out to be, how to make the PersistenceManagerFactory and how to use it to generate PersistenceManagers for me?
2. Do I have to do anything special to achieve JTA? I'd like to be using container managed transactions if possible.
3. Can I set this up to use JNDI to find my JDBC connection?
4. Are there magical files that need to exist to trigger the behavior I want? (I'm looking at you, empty persistence.xml)

Apart from imposing a dependency on JDO and probably DataNucleus directly I'd rather keep this as Java EE 6 as possible, without involving Spring or other third party libraries, but I'd take a third party library over nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/j2ee.html
covers many aspects of Java EE, and gives examples for several Java EE servers including JBoss 7 (the latest spec). It is a contributory effort since nobody uses all such servers; if you have details to add then post them on the DataNucleus forum and they can be included

Comment: So, from that link I take it this is something you can do under J2EE (EJB 2.1, etc.) but it hasn't been updated to Java EE 5/6? If you have time and could expand on that and/or how to use it under Java EE 6 I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: "J2EE" (on the DN docs page) is a generic term (to those of us who've used Java for a long time, no matter what Sun/Oracle change names to) ... JEE. JCA and JTA are covered in that page, and they are still part of that environment, and is what the page purports to. Sadly I don't have time to update it; that's for user contributions for the specific container they're using. JBoss7 is on there

Comment: Ah, someone wants to downvote this. Perhaps next time they'd have the courage to mention why they did that and what extra information they were expecting. I say "perhaps" because I don't expect it

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter (it wasn't me), but looking back over my question and your answer, it's pretty clear that I'm asking about Java EE 6, and your response is a link to pre-EE 6 documentation with a remark that you don't have time to update the documentation.

Comment: There you go, upvoted! I need to know if this approach works on JPA as well. I am trying to use container managed persistence and am unable to find a proper approach for this.(with HBase). Any help?